# How to show text typed in by a user via text box in JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, user-input, alert

I currently have this within my JavaScript code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Form
    </title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var input = document.getElementById('textbox');
         function namet()
        {
        alert(textbox.value);
        }


    var input2 = document.getElementById('location');   
        function namet2()
        {
        alert(location.value);
        }
 </script> 


    </head>

 <body>

 Your name: 
 <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="textbox" <br><br/> 

 Your Address:
 <input type="text" name="address" id="location" <br></br>

 click:
 <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="namet()"/>

 </body>
 </html>
```

...and was looking for a way to gather what the user types within the text box and shows them as in a single alert box when they click on the "Click" button, sort of like a confirmation.

Additionally it would also be helpful to find out how to redirect them to a different page after clicking OK on the alert box.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is easily accomplished, and you almost had it!  Just some misnamed variables...

Given the example you gave, change:

```
7 <script type="text/javascript">
8   
9   var input = document.getElementById('textbox');
10       function namet()
11      {
12      alert(textbox.value);
13      }
14      
15      
16  var input2 = document.getElementById('location');   
17      function namet2()
18      {
19      alert(location.value);
20      }
21 </script>
```

to:

```
7 <script type="text/javascript">
8   
9   var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
10       function namet()
11      {
12      alert(textbox.value);
13      }
14      
15      
16  var location = document.getElementById('location');   
17      function namet2()
18      {
19      alert(location.value);
20      }
21 </script>
```

Hope that helps.

--edit based on comment--

Turn the two individual functions into one, and go ahead and set the variables inside the function, as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showConfirmationDialog() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
    var location = document.getElementById('location');
    alert(textbox.value + '\n' + location.value);
}
</script>

...

<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="showConfirmationDialog();" />
```

--re-edit: Like an idiot, forgot the .value... fixed.

Comment: I'd also recommend putting the variable assignments inside the functions.  If the assignments are executed before the DOM is loaded then they won't contain a reference to the elements.  (Additionally, it's best practice to narrow the scope of variables to the smallest necessary and to keep them as close to their intended use as possible.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer much appreciate it and will definitely consider your comments for the future. However I wanted to display the text from the two textboxes within one alertbox, sort of like a confirmation of what they had typed in. Thanks

Comment: @SpartanMan Updated answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function namet() {
      var input = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
      var input2 = document.getElementById("location").value;   
      alert( "Name : " +input+" Location : " +input2);
      window.location.assign("anypage.html")
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form").submit(function() {
   var fname = $('#fname').val();
   var lname = $('#lname').val();
   alert("First Name:"fname\n"Last Name:"lname);
   });
});
```

and the form

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps